# Cannot configure the spellchecker in Visual Studio 17.5 and 17.6.0 Preview 1.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, spell-checking, editorconfig

My Windows is localized German, but I use the English language pack for Visual Studio and code and documentation is written English first (i.e. we only use German for domain terms without a good English translation).

The spellchecker does not accept English words and suggests German words as corrections; and, of course, does not complain about words that happen to be valid in both languages.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/text-spell-checker?view=vs-2022) it tells me, I need to put `spelling_languages = en-us` in my `.editorconfig` to get what I want, but for some reason, it does not work. I added an `.editorconfig` for this purpose.

The `.editorconfig` is in the same folder as the solution (.sln) file and the C# project (.csproj) file. Its content is the assignment above.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem most likely has nothing to do with the language selection. Everything on my machine is English, and I can't get it to work, either. This is happening because the spell-checking feature of Visual Studio just does not work.

<sub><rant>The spell-checking feature seems to be especially badly implemented, even compared to the average quality of features in visual studio, which is overall quite low. This one is abysmally low. As in: **not working**. A complete waste of time for tens of thousands of programmers all over the world. You might think you are safe from awful user experiences like this by steering clear of any preview versions of visual studio, but even on regular releases Microsoft will push to you features which have been implemented in worse-than-preview quality. This whole product known as visual studio is, nowadays, barely of preview quality. </rant></sub>

On this page: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-1752-Spell-Checker-Exclusion-Di/10328416 you can read about this problem and try and figure out how long it has taken to acknowledge it and to fix it.

It seems to work as of version 17.7.1, which, at the moment I am writing these lines, is just 2 days old. So, your solution should be to upgrade to the latest version of visual studio, (keeping your fingers crossed that they have not broken anything important,) and try again.

Comment: Updated to 17.7.1, it still doesn’t work. Anyways, the link is valuable.